# Windows Universal: Getting Value from ComboBox

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a problem which drives me crazy: Up until Christmas my `C# Rpi` app worked without problems. Coming back from vacation it seems that my ComboBoxes do not work anymore.

I have a method for `"SelectionChanged"` where I try to get the selected value using

```
cbox_SleepState.SelectedIndex. (cbox_SleepState is obviously my ComboBox).
```

Looking at it in the debugger I get this warning:

SelectedIndex - An internal error has occurred while evaluating method Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.Selector.get_SelectedIndex().

I understand why the codes dos not work but I do not get what I need to do to fix this -

especially as the code worked before.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Roger

Comment: I'm assuming an exception was thrown. What is the `InnerException` property value of the thrown exception?

Comment: And maybe a little bit more code to create a context for the issue.

Comment: Did you have some changes  with your app before it cannot work? Could you please refer [mcve] to provide a reproduced project?

Comment: No, no exception is thrown. I have the statement above within an if/else and neitehr the if nor the else fires. I do not  get it at all. I add a breakpoint on the statement  and the watcher just gives me the statement as above when I want to check the "SelectedIndex"

Comment: Basically I am just trying to read the selectedindex of a ComboBox - and it worked as stated. Does somebody have an idea, what the warning actually means? The app just continues working

Comment: @Roger, did you mean this is just a warning showed in output windows, actually it doesn't have influence on your app? Your app can work well?

Comment: Just a brief update: I did a lot of try and errors over the last few days - it works now and I have no clue why.

Comment: @Sunteen: I mean that I ran from within VisualStudio and set a break point in the handler. The break point triggered and I wanted to look at the value in SelectedIndex and got the message described in the debugger when I wanted to access the content.

Comment: @Roger, in that way, please share a [mcve] since I cannot reproduce your  issue. Additionally, it seems like you have resolved your issue right? Did you still need anything want?